# Is it possible to connect to the Google IOTCore via JavaScript in browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, google-cloud-iot

AWS IoT supports this via userPools,  how this can be done via Google Cloud messaging? -Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a JavaScript `MQTT` client, for example Eclipse [Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/); this just needs an external IP.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud IoT Core recommends HTTP bridge for that. (https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/http-bridge)
To establish a connection to HTTP Bridge you have to prepare a private key signed JWT for authentication. The problems will be: where do you store the PK in a secure way in the browser session and how to make a relation between the browser user and IoT device identity?

Btw, 'Google Cloud Messaging' was not part of Google Cloud IoT, was a different product. Now Firebase Cloud Messaging is a recommended product https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Informative reply. Thank you. Compared to AWS IoT this looks straight forward. An API call with user credentials could be used to get JWT. I think this should be ok for subscription only end points.